# How do I create a branch based on an old commit and make my local files reflect that commit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

First I did some Android development in Unity for my project and committed that.

Then I created a Windows build and committed that.

Now I would like to return to Android development and make a new branch for that.

How can I do that in Sourcetree? I'd appreciate non command-line answers since I use the GUI.

I tried right clicking on the older commit and choosing branch and it seemed to create a branch. But I'm stuck trying to make my local files "revert" to that branch. My local files still seem to reflect the Windows build settings.

Edit: Here is how Sourcetree looks like, I can't choose checkout for the branch:
[image]

Comment: You must now checkout that branch : look for this branch in your "Branches" screen and look for a "checkout" action.

Comment: @LeGEC Thanks for helping! The option to checkout seems to be grayed out for the branch. I attached a screenshot to the question. So just to be clear: I'm trying to have a new branch that puts my local files in the state of the commit that says "Decent AA results and no crash"

Comment: Can't you do it from [this screen](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/check-out-a-branch/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You click Branch button on top menu. A dialog box will be displayed.
2. You pick a specified commit and fill name for new branch.

[image]

Comment: Okay and after doing that should the local files on the computer automatically change to reflect that branch or do I need to do some other thing first?

Comment: @user44109  I think the loal files on your computer automatically change to reflect that branch. Do you have any problems?

Comment: I wasn't sure because Unity's build settings stayed the same, but it might actually be that Unity can't store the build platform settings in version control.